# How data can be fetched using php update operation?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, crud, insert-update

I have coded an update operation, but I face problem with my code. When I click on edit button to update the data, the data cannot be fetched from the database and the field of the form is empty. Can you help me fix how to get data in form fields using update operation?

Here is my Code

```
<?php
    require 'database.php';
    $id = null;
    if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    }

    if ( null==$id ) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    if ( !empty($_POST)) {
        // keep track post values
        $file_name = $_POST['file_name'];
$ref_no = $_POST['ref_no'];
$to_name = $_POST['to_name'];
$confidential = $_POST['confidential'];
$designation = $_POST['designation'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$solutation = $_POST['solutation'];
$entity = $_POST['entity'];
$add_1 = $_POST['add_1'];
$thank_you = $_POST['thank_you'];
$add_2 = $_POST['add_2'];
$yours_truly = $_POST['yours_truly'];
$add_3 = $_POST['add_3'];
$sign_name = $_POST['sign_name'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$s_designation = $_POST['s_designation'];
$heading_line_1 = $_POST['heading_line_1'];
$encl_line_1 = $_POST['encl_line_1'];
$heading_line_2 = $_POST['heading_line_2'];
$encl_line_2 = $_POST['encl_line_2'];
$heading_line_3 = $_POST['heading_line_3'];
$encl_line_3 = $_POST['encl_line_3'];
//$text = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['text'] );


    // update data
    $valid = true;
        if ($valid) {
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "UPDATE test  set file_name = ?, ref_no = ?, to_name =?
                                        confidential = ?, designation = ?, date =?
                                        solutation = ?, entity = ?, add_1 =?
                                        thank_you = ?, add_2 = ?, yours_truly =?
                                        add_3 = ?, sign_name = ?, city =?
                                        s_designation = ?, heading_line_1 = ?, encl_line_1 =?
                                        heading_line_2 = ?, encl_line_2 = ?, heading_line_3 =?
                                        encl_line_3 = ?, text = ?
                                                                          WHERE id = ?";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($file_name,$ref_no,$to_name,$confidential,$designation,$date,$solutation,$entity,$add_1,
            $thank_you,$add_2,$yours_truly,$add_3,$sign_name,$city,$s_designation,$heading_line_1,$encl_line_1,$heading_line_2,
            $encl_line_2,$heading_line_3,$encl_line_3,$id));
            Database::disconnect();
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
     else {
       $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM test where id = ?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($id));
        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $file_name = $_POST['file_name'];
$ref_no = $_POST['ref_no'];
$to_name = $_POST['to_name'];
$confidential = $_POST['confidential'];
$designation = $_POST['designation'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$solutation = $_POST['solutation'];
$entity = $_POST['entity'];
$add_1 = $_POST['add_1'];
$thank_you = $_POST['thank_you'];
$add_2 = $_POST['add_2'];
$yours_truly = $_POST['yours_truly'];
$add_3 = $_POST['add_3'];
$sign_name = $_POST['sign_name'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$s_designation = $_POST['s_designation'];
$heading_line_1 = $_POST['heading_line_1'];
$encl_line_1 = $_POST['encl_line_1'];
$heading_line_2 = $_POST['heading_line_2'];
$encl_line_2 = $_POST['encl_line_2'];
$heading_line_3 = $_POST['heading_line_3'];
$encl_line_3 = $_POST['encl_line_3'];
//$text = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['text'] );

        Database::disconnect();
    }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newstyles.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id?>" method="POST" > 
 <table border="0" class="DivTableBorder" width="840px">
      <tr>
        <td class="DivSubHeaderCellTop"  colspan="6">Letters</td>
</tr> <tr>  </td>  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">File Name </td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="480px" colspan="3"><input name="file_name" type="text" id="file_name" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($file_name)?$file_name:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
      <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Referance #</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px"><input name="ref_no" type="text" id="ref_no" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($ref_no)?$ref_no:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td> </tr>

<tr ><td bgcolor="#999999" colspan="4"></td>
 <td class="DivCellText" width="80px"></td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px"></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">To - Name</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="to_name" type="text" id="to_name" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($to_name)?$to_name:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
<td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Confidential</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px">
    <input name="confidential" type="checkbox" id="confidential" value="<?php echo !empty($confidential)?$confidential:'';?>"  />
    </td> </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Designation</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="designation" type="text" id="designation" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($designation)?$designation:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
     <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Date :</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px">
            <input name="date" type="date" id="date" maxlength="255" size="19" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;this.select();lcs(this);" 
        value=18/06/2015 /> 
    </td> </tr>

  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" >&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Solutation</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" >

    <select name='solutation' id='solutation' size='1' STYLE='width: 95%' value="<?php echo !empty($solutation)?$solutation:'';?>" >
    <option value='Others' >[--Others--]</option>
    <option value='Dear Sir' >Dear Sir</option>
    <option value='Madam' >Madam</option>
    </select>
    </td> </tr>

  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Entity</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="entity" type="text" id="entity" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($entity)?$entity:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" >

    <input name="txtSolutation" type="text" id="txtSolutation" 
    value="" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td> </tr>

  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Add-1</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="add_1" type="text" id="add_1" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($add_1)?$add_1:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
         <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Thank You.</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" ><input name="thank_you" type="text" id="thank_you" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($thank_you)?$thank_you:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Add-2</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="add_2" type="text" id="add_2" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($add_2)?$add_2:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
         <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Yours truly</td>
         <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" >
    <select name='yours_truly' id='yours_truly' size='1' STYLE='width: 95%' value="<?php echo !empty($yours_truly)?$yours_truly:'';?>" >
    <option value='1' >Yours truly</option>
    <option value='2' >Regards</option>
    </select>

    </td> </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Add-3</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="add_3" type="text" id="add_3" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($add_3)?$add_3:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Signature-Name</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" >

    <select name='sign_name'  id='sign_name' size='1' style='width:95%' value="<?php echo !empty($sign_name)?$sign_name:'';?>"> 
        <option value='1' >Adnan Afaq</option>
        <option value='2' >Muhammad Shahzad Saleem</option>
        <option value='3' >Adnan Dilawar</option>
        <option value='4' >Rana Muhammad Nadeem</option>
        <option value='5' >Jhangeer Hanif</option>
    </select>
    </td> </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;City</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="city" type="text" id="city" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($city)?$city:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">S-Designation</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px">
    <select name='s_designation' id='s_designation' size='1' STYLE='width: 95%' value="<?php echo !empty($s_designation)?$s_designation:'';?>" >
    <option value='1' >Managing Director</option>
    <option value='2' >Chief Operating Officer</option>
    <option value='3' >Manager Ratings</option>
    <option value='4' >Unit Head Ratings</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Heading Line-1</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="480px" colspan="3"><input name="heading_line_1" type="text" id="heading_line_1" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($heading_line_1)?$heading_line_1:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  maxlength="55"/>
    </td>
     <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Encl: Line-1</td>
     <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" >
     <input name="encl_line_1" type="text" id="encl_line_1" value="<?php echo !empty($encl_line_1)?$encl_line_1:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Heading Line-2</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="480px" colspan="3"><input name="heading_line_2" type="text" id="heading_line_2" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($heading_line_2)?$heading_line_2:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"    maxlength="55" />
    </td>
     <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Line-2</td>
     <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" >
     <input name="encl_line_2" type="text" id="encl_line_2" value="<?php echo !empty($encl_line_2)?$encl_line_2:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
  </tr>  
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Heading Line-3</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="480px" colspan="3"><input name="heading_line_3" type="text" id="heading_line_3" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($heading_line_3)?$heading_line_3:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"    maxlength="55" />
    </td>
     <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Line-3</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px">
         <input name="encl_line_3" type="text" id="encl_line_3" value="<?php echo !empty($encl_line_3)?$encl_line_3:'';?>" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr ><td bgcolor="#999999" colspan="6"></td></tr>
<tr ><td colspan="6">
 <table  border="0" class="DivTableBorder" width="840px">
 <tr>
<td class="DivCellText" colspan="4">
<textarea rows="20" cols="100" id="text" name="text" style="font-size:14px;" value="<?php echo !empty($text)?$text:'';?>" ></textarea> </td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td width="734">

</td>
<td  colspan="6" ><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Cancel"  /> </td>
<td width="44" colspan="6">

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></input>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
<div class="form-actions">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                          <a class="btn" href="index.php">Back</a>
                        </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to set `WHERE id = '$id'`